# How to extract specific String from pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This my dataframe df:

```
    Repository
0   ParaskP7/android-dev-sources
1   uholeschak/ediabaslib
2   t3hk0d3/ruby_faceapp
3   prateekbh/hopon
4   c0i/cocos2d-x-v2
5   risk1996/ctg-cheat
6   GiacomoPignoni/undercover_discord_bot
7   vyasishanatc194/Crowdbotics-React-Native-Test
```

I need to extarct the sting after ' / ' for exemple for the first row I need to extract 'android-dev-sources'

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('result_refactorings.csv', sep=';')
refactoring_details = df['repository']
a=repo_Name.to_frame(name=refactoring_details)
a.repository.str.extract(r'')
```

the problem is with the extract function , I can't define my pattern

Any help please .Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Method 1: `str.split`

```
df['Repository'].str.split(r'/').str[1]

0              android-dev-sources
1                       ediabaslib
2                     ruby_faceapp
3                            hopon
4                     cocos2d-x-v2
5                        ctg-cheat
6           undercover_discord_bot
7    Crowdbotics-React-Native-Test
Name: Repository, dtype: object
```

---

## Method 2: `str.extract`

Using regex:

```
df['Repository'].str.extract('\/(.*)')

                               0
0            android-dev-sources
1                     ediabaslib
2                   ruby_faceapp
3                          hopon
4                   cocos2d-x-v2
5                      ctg-cheat
6         undercover_discord_bot
7  Crowdbotics-React-Native-Test
```